# MVC viewmodel is null on post (editing multiple rows)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and have been searching for a solution to this problem for hours. I'm trying to create a site where admins can go in and approve registration user requests and also assign them to a user group. I'm getting data from multiple tables so I created a viewmodel.

I finally have the GET Edit controller working to display the data, but can't figure out how the POST Edit should work. When I was debugging, I realized that the viewmodel I was trying to return had only null values.

I'm not sure if there are many things wrong with this code or just one. On postback, I need to update some values in the Access table. If you need more information from me, just let me know. Thanks!

**ViewModel:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AccessRequests.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AccessRequests.ViewModels
{
    public class UserAccessData
    {
        public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Access> Accesses { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
// GET: Accesses/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(string brand, string group)
{
    var viewModel = new UserAccessData();

    viewModel.Users = db.Users
        .Include(i => i.Accesses)
        .OrderBy(i => i.UserName);

    viewModel.UserGroups = db.UserGroups
        .Where(i => i.Groups.Contains(group));

    if (brand != null)
    {
        viewModel.Accesses = db.Accesses
            .Include(x => x.User)
            .Where(x => x.Brand.ToUpper() == brand);
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}

// POST: Accesses/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Access access, UserAccessData editaccess)
{
    //code here
}
```

**View:**

```
@model AccessRequests.ViewModels.UserAccessData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit Access</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                    <th>Region</th>
                    <th>User Group</th>
                    <th>Approve</th>
                    <th>Deny Reason</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Accesses)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FirstName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.LastName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Email)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Company)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Role)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Region)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserGroups, new SelectList(Model.UserGroups, "Groups", "GroupDescription"), "Please select a User Group")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Approved, new SelectList(
                              new List<Object>{
                                   new { value = 0 , text = ""  },
                                   new { value = "YES" , text = "YES" },
                                   new { value = "NO" , text = "NO"}
                                },"value","text", 2))
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.DenyReason, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.DenyReason, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't use a 'postback'.

Comment: which values do you want to POST? try using a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to post to a collection property, your field names need to be in the form of something like: `Accesses[0].Approved`, `Accesses[1].Approved`, etc. In order to achieve that, you need to use a `for` loop rather than `foreach`. You'll also need to change your property's type from `IEnumerable<Access>` to `List<Access>`.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Accesses.Count(); i++)
{
    ...
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Accesses[i].Approved, ...)
}
```

Also, bear in mind that only those properties which have actual HTML fields that participate in the the post will have values in your post action. Everything else will either be null or whatever default value the property may have. If you save an entity with properties that have been nulled out because they weren't posted, you will overwrite those properties in your database. You need to take care to either make sure all the necessary data comes through in the post or that you repopulate said data from the the database before attempting to save anything.

Comment: Ok, but switching to List<Access> gives me errors in my controller GET. How do I add a where statement to the List type?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I just needed to add .ToList() to the end. Thanks!